# Rust program occasionally gives inconsistent results

Tags: rust

I am working on part 1 of day 9 of the [Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2015/day/9) in Rust and ran into a strange problem. I wrote the following code, which works usually, but about 10% of the time it gives the wrong answer.

```
extern crate permutohedron;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

use permutohedron::LexicalPermutation;

fn get_distance(cities: &[Rc<String>], paths: &HashMap<(Rc<String>, Rc<String>), i64>) -> i64 {
    cities.iter().fold((0, None), |(sum, last_city), city| {
        (last_city.map_or(0, |last_city| {
            sum + *paths.get(&(last_city, city.clone())).unwrap()
        }), Some(city.clone()) )
    }).0
}

fn main() {

    let file = File::open("input_9.txt").unwrap();
    let file = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut paths = HashMap::new();
    let mut cities = HashMap::new();

    for line in file.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let mut words = line.split(' ');
        let from = words.nth(0).unwrap();
        let to = words.nth(1).unwrap();

        if !cities.contains_key(from) {
            cities.insert(from.to_owned(), Rc::new(from.to_owned()));
        }
        if !cities.contains_key(to) {
            cities.insert(to.to_owned(), Rc::new(to.to_owned()));
        }

        let from = cities.get(from).unwrap();
        let to = cities.get(to).unwrap();

        let dist = words.nth(1).unwrap().parse::<i64>().unwrap();
        paths.insert((from.clone(), to.clone()), dist);
        paths.insert((to.clone(), from.clone()), dist);
    }

    let mut cities_perm: Vec<_> = cities.values().map(|k| k.clone()).collect();

    let mut min_path = None;
    loop {
        let dist = get_distance(&cities_perm, &paths);

        min_path = Some(min_path.map_or(dist, |v|
            *[v, dist].iter().min().unwrap()
        ));

        if !cities_perm.next_permutation() { break }
    }

    println!("{}", min_path.unwrap());

}
```

I am running it with `cargo run`, and never changing the file `input_9.txt`, so I see no reason this should ever give different answers. I also tried building it, then running the executable that it built directly, like `./target/debug/day_9`, and the same thing happens. I noticed it tends to give wrong results most often soon after building it, rather than later.

Usually, I am getting `141`, which is correct. However it will sometimes print something like `210`, `204`, or `155`. Why would this be happening?

Here's the input to the program in case it helps you: https://pastebin.com/XJzsMy5A

Comment: Inserting `cities_perm.sort();` right after `let mut cities_perm` fixes the problem, so maybe there is some issue with `permutohedron` crate?

Comment: Thank you! After looking at the `permutohedron` docs, it suggests that the order of the slice passed matters, although it's not explicitly stated. And since `HashMap::values` returns values in a random order, it makes since that it'd work sometimes and not others.

Comment: Great that you solved the issue!

Comment: Some offtopic nitpicking, if I may - don't overuse abstractions, they make stuff harder to read. For example, `if dist < min_path { min_path = dist; }` is much easier to read than `min_path = Some(min_path.map_or(dist, |v| *[v, dist].iter().min().unwrap()));`.

Comment: I used `std::i64::MAX`. I agree that in some situations Option approach may be nicer - for example, it may automatically handle the case with empty array - but in some other situations it may be more readable to use simpler solution. And I'm not sure that Rust compiler (as great as it is) will be able to optimize such code with iterators and options and stuff into simple comparison.

Comment: Yeah, `std::i64::MAX` doesn't look nearly as bad. Thank you

Comment: At that point `min_path = std::cmp::min(min_path, dist)` is clearer. `min_path = Some(min_path.map_or(dist, |v| min(v, dist)))` isn't bad either.

Comment: Yes, `std::cmp::min` makes everything much better. My main gripe here was `[].iter().min().unwrap()`. @Shepmaster, you are obviously an expert, can you tell - will rust compiler be able replace that `[].iter().min()` with simple comparison without all those wrappers?

Comment: @Rogach not that *exact* one, but [one that does the same thing is the same number of instructions](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=5f2b89ea14262c5615ba9a4b13cd5da9&version=stable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that calling `next_permutation` gives you the next "ordered permutation" ([link to the docs](https://docs.rs/permutohedron/0.2.2/permutohedron/trait.LexicalPermutation.html#tymethod.next_permutation)).

The caveat here is that you are not iterating permutations that are lexicaly ordered before the input slice - for example, if you started with this path:

```
["Norrath", "Faerun", "Tristram", "Tambi", "Straylight", "Snowdin", "Arbre", "AlphaCentauri"]
```

You will never arrive to this path:

```
["Arbre", "Snowdin", "Norrath", "Faerun", "Tambi", "Tristram", "AlphaCentauri", "Straylight"]
```

And since `HashMap` does not guarantee keys or values ordering, `cities_perm` ordering is different on each run, thus you iterate different subsets of all possible permutations and get different results.

One solution may be to sort the cities before starting permutations:

```
cities_perm.sort();
```

Comment: A `BTreeMap` is implicitly ordered and an easier change.